# The tab "Latest Version" does not appear and neither is the path /latest working (Drupal 9.5.8)

Tags: workflows

I have the modules *Workflows* and *Group content moderation* installed. I also configured a workflow for a particular content type.
My problem is that although I can change the moderation state in the "*edit*" mode of the node I don't see the tab "*Latest version*" on the node's page. I tried the path `www.my-domain.com/node/123/latest`, but all I receive is the "*page not found*" message.
I am logged in as Admin and I have the permissions to see the latest version. The permission "view all unpublished entities" is also set.
What am I missing? Any hints are appreciated.